# How to set up LAN Printer with IP address

Tags: printing, lan, ip-address

On a Moto G (5) Plus running Android 8.1.0, API 27, I have `Default Print Service` under `Settings > Connected devices > Printing`.

When I click on `Default Print Service` it starts searching for printers, which doesn't return anything, even though my printer and phone are on 192.168.3.x (my home LAN).  I can click the 3 dot menu and  click `Add printer`, then under *Add manual printer*, I type the IP address of the printer, but the result is immediate:

> Printer not supported

The printer is connected to the LAN through a JetDirect 300X (yes, very old technology).  But the printer works fine when configured to receive output from Windows machines.  On Windows, I put in the IP address, Port Number `9100`, protocol `Raw`.  The driver is `HP LaserJet5`, which comes with Windows.

Beyond the default print service, I also tried and HP Print Service that I found on GooglePlay, but I could not find a way to manually add a printer using that.

Is there a way to get my phone to print to this LAN connected printer?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a Moto X4, also running Android 8.1.0 (LineageOS). My printer is a Brother laser model that definitely supports both [IPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) on the default port 631 and [JetDirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetDirect) on port 9100. The two most bog-standard network printing technologies… and yet Android doesn't recognize it at all.

Has _anyone_ ever gotten Android's “Default Print Service” to work? ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

I have been through a similar struggle, but a Brother HL-2250DN networked printer and Android Pie. Printer is not showing up when searching in Default Print Service.

I can see the Brother printer on the network using Fing, and can ping it by its IP address so it isn't a network problem.

The Brother supports Internet Protocol Printing (IPP) which is apparently supported by Android, but I'm not convinced Brother's implementation is good. It also supports other protocols supported by Android, but enabling them all doesn't make the printer show up.

I discovered if I shared the printer from my Mac, it did then show up in Default Print Service, and I can print from my Android. Unfortunately, sharing from Windows doesn't seem to work in this way.

It would be nice not to need another client powered on in order to print, but that probably requires a printer natively supporting Google Cloud Print or properly implementing an Android supported promoting protocol.

Comment: I too have a Brother HL-series laser printer, as I [commented on the question]( https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207950/how-to-set-up-lan-printer-with-ip-address#comment326840_207950). It also supports IPP on port 631 and JetDirect on port 9100, and yet Android can't connect to it at all. As far as I can tell, Brother's implementation of both of these is absolutely bog-standard. Is there any documentation on _what/how_ Android's Default Printing Services _actually supports_?

Answer (score 2):

There's an app that I got to work called [Let's Print Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackspruce.lpd).

Comment: This app did find my Brother HL-2250DN and I was able to print a test page by selecting Raw. However, printers added to the app don't appear in the Android print system on Android 10 so can't be used to print from apps. Frustrating as it seemed close! The app seems very old, without any development since 2017.  I guess since then Android has changed the way printer plugins work.

Answer (score 0):

Hp Epson all offer apps for print from smartphone. Download those app and connect to printer.

Even you can use usb cable to connect to printer. Otherwise use Wi-Fi or Bluetooth connection.

Use google drive to print a document.

Or on chrome browser go to setting  /advance / printing / manage cloud print / add printer.